# Reading from app.config yields null results

Tags: c#

My issue is as the title reads, when I attempt to get some app settings for a given key, I am always returned with null.
I have 2 projects, 1 .Net Core Class library and 1 .Net Core Test Solution. Both contain an identical `app.config`.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJ7V.jpg.
Here is the solution explorer so you can see the project set up.

In my tests solution, I am trying to test the validity of my helper using this test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSaveLocationHelper()
{
    ConfigurationResponseMessage connectionString = ConfigurationHelper.GetSaveLocation();
    Assert.IsTrue(connectionString.ResponseCode == ResponseCode.SUCCESS);
}
```

I wrote a helper method that calls the `configurationManager`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

namespace Unity.Helpers
{
    public static class ConfigurationHelper
    {
        public static ConfigurationResponseMessage GetSaveLocation()
        {
            string saveLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.SAVE_LOCATION];

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveLocation))
                return new ConfigurationResponseMessage()
                {
                    ConfigString = saveLocation,
                    ResponseCode = ResponseCode.SUCCESS
                };

            return new ConfigurationResponseMessage()
            {
                ConfigString = string.Empty,
                ResponseCode = ResponseCode.FAILURE
            };
        }
    }
}
```

`saveLcoation` is always null

`Constants.SAVE_LOCATION = 'SaveLocation'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
  <add key="SaveLocation" value="D:/test.json"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Not entirely sure what is wrong. Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the problem only in the unit test or in the real code too?

Comment: Your test project also needs the same app.config file

Comment: That's wired, maybe you should check if the app.config file configed as "always copy", which means it will be copied to bin\Debug or bin\Release, check there.

Comment: @Alejandro I assume with the class library, saveLocation always = null

Comment: @WildWind they were set to nothing, ive changed the build action to Content and Copy To output directory as always, still getting the same issue

Comment: @CeriWestcott Could you post the part of `UnityLevelManager.Tests.csproj` that shows how the compilation behavior for App.config file is configured